# Function that returns 1 or 0

Tags: c, algorithm

My prompt is the following:

Write the definition of a function named  alternator that receives no parameters  and returns 1 the first time it is invoked, returns 0 the next time it is invoked, then 1, 0 and so on, alternating between  1/0 on successive invocations.

my attempt is:

```
int alternator(void) {

    static int x = 0;

    if(x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return 1;
        x++;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
        x++;
    }

}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Since `x` starts at `0`, the first `if` fires every time, returning `1`, and the rest of the code is never reached.

Comment: Even if you add the increment, you will eventually invoke _undefined behaviour_ (crap, the question was closed just before I could complete my answer).

Answer (score 4):

I prefer `xor` for this since there is no upper limit on the number if times you can call `alternator`:

```
int alternator(void) {
    static int x = 0;  // set to 1 if you want 0 as first value...
    return x ^= 1;
}
```

Demo:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%d   %d\n", i, alternator());
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
0   1
1   0
2   1
3   0
4   1
5   0
6   1
7   0
8   1
9   0
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, you can also do:

```
int alternator(void) {
    static int x = 0;
    return x = !x;
}
```

Comment: Or if you don't fancy bit-twiddling, there's `return x = !x;`

Comment: "... since there is no upper limit on values" What do you mean? It only uses values `0` and `1` anyway.

Comment: @Olaf I think dawg is referring to the `x++` in the question (though never executed).

Comment: The OP's solution has `x++` which will eventually overflow the signed int. Gracefully maybe, depending on the platform, but one should do that only with forethought. Signed int overflow is, technically, [undefined behavior.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You have `x++` after `return`ing, so the increment never occurs.

Comment: Hopefully there is a compiler warning in the compile output...

Comment: The increments will eventually invoke UB! Look at the type of `x`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
int alternator(void) {
    static int x = 0;
    return x ^= 1;
}
```

Comment: Or if you don't fancy bit-twiddling, there's `return x = (x + 1) & 1;`

Comment: Or if you *still* think that's bit-twiddling, there's `return x = (x + 1) % 2;`

Comment: No bit-twiddling `return x = "\1"[x];`

Comment: @Blastfurnace nice one.

Answer (score 0):

When a function returns nothing after the return will be executed.

Currently to the run-time your function looks like:

```
int alternator(void) {

    static int x = 0;

    if(x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

because that is all that will ever be executed.

What you need to do is change the value of `x` each time the function is run and then return that value.

A simple `if` statement which detects whether the value of `x` is `1` or `0` would be sufficient.

It is also a good idea to usually only have one return statement at the end of the function and manipulate the return value within the function. This make the code more readable and easier to follow.

A reasonable attempt would look like:

```
int alternator(void) {

    static int x = 0;

    if(x == 0) 
    {
        x = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: You can replace all of that `if/else` code with `x = 1 - x;` or an XOR

Comment: @Blastfurnace I could but that would be less readable and reduce the granularity when debugging. For experienced programmers that would be fine but with newer programmers the more granular the program is the better, just so they can debug easier.

Comment: I think `return x = !x;` is pretty clear.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker untill they do `return x == !x` because they aren't used to having assignments on the same line as returns... But that's beside the point. I agree is clear and does look nice but I went for simple just to teach some good practices.

Answer (score 0):

The code highlighted below is unreachable code:

else if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return 1;
        **x++;**
    }
    else {
        return 0;
        **x++;**
    }

Comment: The increments will eventually invoke UB! Look at the type of `x`